# Packet count per mac address on wireless network

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, encryption, mac-address, wpa2-psk

I'd like to get to know how many packets get transferred to a certain MAC address in my wireless network, protected with WPA2. I'm not at all interested in the contents of the packets, I'd just need a count.

My setup is as follows: I have a laptop generating traffic and I want a packet count to that laptop, and I have a second laptop (running Linux, CLI) monitoring the network.

I've tried putting the interface on the monitoring laptop into monitor mode with airmon-ng: `airmon-ng start wlan0`. After that I can capture "some" packets with `tshark -I -i mon0 -n -f "ether host 60:36:dd:15:be:d1"` (with 60:36:dd:15:be:d1 the MAC address of my laptop wireless network card). However, all of this data shows up as "QoS Data". Elsewhere I read that encrypted packets (for example TCP/UDP) simply should show up as "Data".

The strange thing is, monitoring the network with airodump-ng (`airodump-ng mon0 --bssid 25:c9:b1:2e:36:48 --channel 3`) detects the AP client I want the count of. The counters do go up each time I generate traffic. Sadly, tshark doesn't detect this Data.

My question: is there a way tshark can display the encrypted (or unencrypted - it's my network, I know the key) packets with a certain MAC address destination?

Comment: This is generally easier to do with statistics from the access point, though what's available varies with access point (and/or firmware, if multiple firmware options are available.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal: Thank you for your answer. However, I want to monitor multiple MAC adresses. The data gets processed on the monitoring laptop, so using tshark would be much more practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QoS Data` frames are the frames you're looking for. `QoS Data` frames are just `Data` frames from a device that knows how to do QoS. 802.11n, 802.11ac, and later require QoS, so basically all 802.11n, 802.11ac, and later data frames are going to show up as `QoS Data`.

The documentation you were looking at that only mentioned `Data` frames must have been written way back in the A/B/G days. Or perhaps it was written for an audience that was expected to know 802.11 well enough to know that the distinction between `Data` and `QoS Data` frames is irrelevant in this context.

It's still possible to see non-QOS `Data` frames in modern-day packet captures, but it usually indicates that you have an 802.11g or earlier client on your network.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification, that's what I was looking for!